# How can I add a script to the Gnome 3 launcher

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, gnome3

Programs like eclipse and intellij are launched via scripts, how can I add those programs to the gnome 3 launcher?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between "program" and "script" in this case – you can launch anything that can be launched by the kernel.

Most desktop environments, including GNOME, Unity and KDE, keep application data in `.desktop` files according to XDG [Desktop Entry specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html). You can create them with any text editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/usr/bin/eclipse
Icon=eclipse
Terminal=false
```

Save the file as `myapp.desktop` and put it in one of these directories:

- `~/.local/share/applications/` for the current user,
- or `/usr/local/share/applications` for the entire system.

(There also is `/usr/share/applications`, reserved for programs installed through the package manager.)

Once you create the file and put it in the right place, it should automatically appear in GNOME under "Applications".

---

Icons follow the [Icon Naming specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) and are kept in:

- `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor` for the current user;
- `/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor` for the entire system;
- `/usr/share/icons/hicolor` for programs installed through the package manager.

For example, if you had a 64x64 icon for Eclipse, it could go to `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/eclipse.png` and you would use `Icon=eclipse` in the .desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

I get it!
If I change the ~/ with /home/username in the exec line it works! Probably the command is launched as root.